# Run multiple Firebase TextRecognition processes in parallel

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

i am trying to process more than 2 camera frames in parallel at the same time. So i have 2 text detectors initialized like this

```
TextRecognitionProcessor textRecognitionProcesso0 = FirebaseVision.getInstance(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context), Integer.valueOf(0).toString())).getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

TextRecognitionProcessor textRecognitionProcesso1 = FirebaseVision.getInstance(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context), Integer.valueOf(1).toString())).getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

textRecognitionProcesso0.processImage(frame1);
textRecognitionProcesso1.processImage(frame2);
```

Yet i don't see any performance improvement at all. When i do a profiling i see only one thread utilizing the CPU. It seems like ML kit runs them sequentially. Does firebase ML kit support running multiple OCR detectors in parallel ?

Comment: I have heard of people doing this with barcode detection. However, I have also heard that text recognition uses a lot of memory, and having more than one might be problematic for your app's memory use.

Comment: Hello @DougStevenson I updated my Question. Now my question shows exactly what i intend to do.

Comment: The API docs say "Note there is only one instance of on-device FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer and under the same FirebaseVision."  So maybe you are just using the same one twice. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/FirebaseVision.html#getOnDeviceTextRecognizer()

Comment: I would contact Firebase support directly to ask the question, so you will get a response from the engineering team about the actual capabilities.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes there is only one per FirebaseVision. To avoid this limitation i call FirebaseApp.initializeApp with a unique name so that i get two distinct TextRecognitionProcessor instances

Comment: I read the documentation as saying there is only one text processor, period. For all of FirebaseVision.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use [standalone MLKit SDK](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2), where you can set [custom executor](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/text/latin/TextRecognizerOptions.Builder#setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) for each [TextRecognizer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/text/TextRecognizer)

Comment: Set custom executor for each TextRecognizer cannot make them run in parallel.